# Glimpse PagerType.ContinuousPaging Continuously Loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, plugins, glimpse

I'm attempting to write my own Log4Net Glimpse plugin (so I can interface with my custom MySql database).  I'm running into an issue though.  When I click `more` from inside my plugin, `Loading...` appears and the result set comes back (the `Raw` result from Fiddler is pasted below), but `Loading...` stays up and the results are never copied to the set on the page.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 01:31:19 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 171
Connection: Close

[["Id","Date","Thread","Level","Logger","Message","Exception"],[1,new Date(1326341298000),"15","DEBUG","MySite.WebGUI.Controllers.AccountController","In SignUp!","",""]]
```

*Note: The result set image below goes from 11 to 2 (7 through 2 not shown).*

[image]

Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: Do you happen to have the source handy? Are you using the pagging support within glimpse For this plugin? Is there a client side error coming up?

Comment: I'm using the `IProvideGlimpsePaging` and chrome's inspector is not showing any errors coming through.  If you want I could clean up the source and throw it on git or something if that would help.  FYI my setup is almost identical to the Glimpse.Elmah plugin's source since I'm using it as a reference: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Elmah/Plugin/Elmah.cs

Comment: Humm if you are basing things on the elmah plugin I don't know why you would have trouble. It would be great of you could throw up the code on github.

Comment: Sure.  Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/1612723  Thanks again for taking the time to look into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is: JSON.parse unexpected keyword.
The error is being thrown because of the date you're returning. It's being sent down to the client like this: new Date(1326341298000), but it should like something like this: /Date(1326341298000)/